# jquery add callback method after redirect to new page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

How to add a callback function,i.e, when the page is loaded i need to show an alert

```
   var url = "http://stackoverflow.com";    
    $(location).attr('href',url)
```

Comment: write load event on the page where you want to display that alert/

Answer (score 0):

You may try this. there is a client side window loaded event. You may write your code or set alert here . one more option is to write your code in document.ready function.                                                                                 Like This

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      alert("document ready occurred!");
});

$(window).load(function() {
      alert("window load occurred!");
});
```